# How can I make an UltraTextEditor keep my line breaks in edit mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have a winform with an `Infragistics` `UltraTextEditor` control. I can type in enter while editing the text. It saves just fine.

[image]

However, if I go back into edit mode, the control collapses the text into the same line.

[image]

If I leave the control the text resumes its normal format with the line breaks.

How can I make it keep my line breaks in edit mode?

Comment: Think ya might have uploaded the thumbnails there chief. My eyes don't C# as they used to..

Comment: @CaiusJard Better?

Comment: I can see where to point my magnifier now! :D :D

Comment: @Randy: Can you upload screenshots in 1:1: resolution at least? We're going to need to see some code. Please edit your post to include the code you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for this is when UltraTextEditor enters in edit mode it is rendering MS TextBox and this is where the editing happens. The important thing here is `MS TextBox` is able to show new lines only when they are represented with `\r\n`, while `UltraTextEditor` will show new lines even if they are represented only with `\n`. This will end with displaying the new lines when not in edit mode, editor handle this, not displaying new lines when in edit mode, `TextBox` cannot handle this.

If you are manipulating the Value of the editor and changing the new lines from `\r\n` to `\n` this is why you are facing this problem. Note manipulating the value does not exactly means you go and change the new lines. This could happen if you, for example, save the value somewhere, e.g. in XML file, and then load it back to the editor.

If you do not find where the new lines got broken you can try to fix the new lines in editor's `EnterEditMode` event.